# values in dropdown of configurable products attributes in listing page of magento

Tags: magento

This is my product description page.
[image]

In the dropdown of color there is a list.i want this list (red,green,blue) in my product listing page.
thats here:-[image]

How to get the value of configurable products in product listing page?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hay, you can use custom option on your product. It's that right?

Comment: why custom option? how? @thiha I want all options in my product listing page.

Comment: If you want to display custom options list you can check this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4480/custom-options-in-product-list/4499#4499

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to Magento admin panel. Then, go to Manage Product under Catalog Menu.
2. Click on you product. Then, it will show product detail.
3. You will see Custom Option on Left Menu. Click on this
4. Click on Add New Option
5. After that, type display name on Title eg. Color
6. Choose Drop-Down on Input Type
7. New Box appear. So, you can add Red on Title. Then, click to Add New Row. You should add 3 row based on your requirement. Then, save.
8. If you don't see any thing on front-end UI, Clear Cache and ReIndex Manage again.

Hope this help

Comment: This is not an answer to question , op want to display custom options list on product listing page, by doing this custom options only visible to product detail page.